# Stack Overflow not reachable via IPv6

Tags: feature-request

Stack Overflow has no AAAA record and is not reachable via IPv6, are there any reasons not supporting IPv6?
This question has been discussed on Stack Exchange a few times (7 years ago!) but now in 2017 IPv6 is still not working:

- [Would it be possible for Stack Overflow to be accessible over IPv6?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21592/would-it-be-possible-for-stack-overflow-to-be-accessible-over-ipv6)
- [Stack Overflow over IPv6 on World IPv6 Launch Day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134740/stack-overflow-over-ipv6-on-world-ipv6-launch-day)

Are there any plans for IPv6 support?

Comment: Why should they support IPv6? What is it that it will give as user experience that IPv4 doesn't? SO is plenty fast and usable already as-is. IPv6 is a relief and convenience for the data carriers, not the end points. Such questions/demands i see posted by "IPv6 activists" trying to "shame" companies into supporting something that has no user benefit ...

Comment: it's not about trying to "shame" stackoverflow for that fact. the reason i'm asking is that i tried to reach stackoverflow from an ipv6 only vserver, and there we are...

Comment: there is something wrong with your IPv6 config then. IPv6 was designed to handle that... where is your NAT64/DNS64 proxy?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331191/168273

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Honest answer? We haven't gotten to it yet. It's a non-trivial time sink and we just haven't had that chunk of time to spend on it yet. It's not a high priority, or we'd allocate the (large) amount of time this requires.

Off the top of my head, here's what needs doing:

- IP allocations (we have the blocks from ARIN already)
- Work on all 8 ISP connections to our data centers (BGP, etc.)
- Research everyone who'd hit us for IPv6 (for firewall rules)
- All firewall rules need to be duplicated in IPv6 form
- Logging *everywhere* we record an IP would have to change
- Rewriting any and all code with IPv4 format assumptions (logging)
- Rewrite of `X-Forwarded-For` handling
- Expanding database fields (and adding them) for IPv6 length (let's not even talk about IPv6to4)
- Rewriting all of the mod dashboards/tooling that query based on IP
- Rate limiting backend code (and time buckets)
- CDN/Proxy setup (Fastly)
- Load balancer bindings (front and backends)
- Load balancer ACLs

(Edit) Adding additional things as our internal chat comes up with them to make this as helpful as possible to others:

- GeoIP databases (we have a custom implementation for speed) would need to be written and tested. Memory usage and accuracy is also a concern there.
- Proxy IPv6to6, 4to6 (and back again?) handling for X-FF would be new.

...and it's really not worth using internally. Not at our size. So we're likely talking about a 6to4 transition at the door (HAProxy). Or we go IPv6 internally and make our lives much easier and harder at the same time (it definitely goes both ways). That has a whole other set of issues again with firewalls, routing, etc.

It's just a lot of work for honestly not a lot of gain just yet. Things like HTTPS and HTTP/2 are far more impactful for users. We'll get to IPv6 eventually, but it's unlikely to happen any time soon. There are simply far more impactful things we can do with our time on the sysadmin front for the foreseeable future.

(Edit) Let me clarify something important: **This is something everyone on our SRE team would like to do**. We just don't have the time yet, even more important things are in queue.

Comment: So, 6 to 8 weeks, then?

Comment: One issue with IPv6 is that many folk get millions of IPv6 addresses, and that their routers typically don't use a single one but cycle it pretty often (e.g. every time they restart their computer). Perhaps it's possible to see which IPv6 addresses "belong" to the same person with prefixlen or something (not a networking expert) thuogh. Either way, it will make tools like IP crossref that much harder to make, if not impossible.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker there's some of that, and some of the technical side on the routing as well. At this point IPv6 isn't segmented enough to be a route table growth problem (we run full tables on all routers), but it'll be interesting to see if it becomes one. Hopefully we don't repeat the mistakes of v4 (that, to be fair, didn't really become an issue until depletion).

Comment: I coulda sworn SO used CloudFlare for DNS. CloudFlare automatically bridges IPv6 to IPv4

Comment: @Machavity - [not anymore](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323537/cloudflare-is-ruining-stack-overflow-for-me-with-its-recaptcha#comment363435_323673)

Comment: @Machavity "automatically" is not an accurate statement. Much of the above still applies, and doing that creates many other issues - such as IP banning the wrong people.

Comment: Fastly can do 6 to 4 as well. A smaller number of things would need to support it, but still more than zero.

Comment: @captncraig not a small number, it only saves 2-4 items above max (and those are the simpler ones).

Comment: iOS Apps are required to work on iPv6 only networks, how is the SO iOS app running? The servers it talks to are iPv6? Or I guess it just uses the IPV6 version of the IPv4 address? (sorry, not a network guru)

Comment: Interesting read, until I hit the word "impactful" and my leg automatically kicked out.  I've got two broken toes and a busted cpu case now.  I'll send the bill.

Comment: Do you need some more excuses? http://ipv6excuses.com/

Comment: @Carpetsmoker The ISP is supposed to give each customer a quadrillion IP addresses, and you can easily use that to know if two addresses are supposed to belong to the same customer. Don't trust anybody who says IPv6 makes that harder to achieve, because CGN has already made it impossible to do with IPv4.

Comment: @NickCraver IP banning doesn't work anyway and should not be used.

Comment: @SargeBorsch keep telling yourself that, I'll be over here in reality where it can be immensely useful :)

Comment: @NickCraver well, in practice this usually means that all Tor exit nodes are banned, and legitimate users can't use Tor and get pissed off, attracting their friends to alternatives too. Also even if we forget about Tor, there are dynamic and shared IP addresses, in several big countries **the majority** of users get them.

Comment: @SargeBorsch "doesn't work *well* in *some specific cases*" != "doesn't work". For example, we can readily ban requests from botnets with only a few thousand IPs attacking us from compromised systems. Show me alternatives that don't exhaust bandwidths at our endpoints, I'll wait here :)

Comment: @NickCraver get a few thousand ground-to-ground missiles and neutralize the botnet once and for all :D

Comment: @gman - that's a concern of the IPv6-only ISPs that they have tackled already because 99% of the internet traffic is over IPv4 - so the ISPs who want to do pure IPv6 (no dual stack) have to bridge it. Apple's demand was that iOS apps do not trip by implying they'll always see IPv4 on their socket ends

Comment: Wow, that list sounds like a big lack of foresight.

Comment: [feature-request]: make honest answers the default :P

Comment: @AndrasDeak My answers fall into 4 categories, I can't speak for the rest of the team. Personally, my 4 are: smartass, intolerable smartass, honest, and brutally honest.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart not really. We made conscious decisions along the way. It's not worth the cost and never has been for the life of this company. When that changes, we'll do it. Much more important things have been in queue before IPv6. I'm working on a blog post about HTTPS right now that'll shed a little light into how extensive that list of other things is.

Comment: and what's about api.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @cyptus The problem set is basically the same for all properties, including the API - was that the question?

Comment: What are those arguments about proxies are supposed to mean? Nobody is requesting IPv6-only access. It could run totally fine on a dual-stack setting. All the administrative tools can remain how they are on IPv4 until they are ported as well. Don't do a roll-out in one day. Do it gradually. Everything else is not tech-worthy...

Comment: @NasBanov - That's bs. 99% if internet traffic is IPv4 because the servers on the other end only respond to IPv4. Look, however, at Google's statistics, and they're seeing around 20% of traffic coming in over IPv6.

Comment: @TJJ The proxies have all the same set of requirements to enable IPv6 regardless of whether IPv4 goes away. The admin tools aren't the issue, *the client data in the tools* is the issue. They're inseparable once clients can connect on IPv6. As are most of these items, almost every once is required for the *first* client to connect and work. The remains not-a-priority, we have more important things to do way ahead of getting into this. I personally have a list at least 2 years long. Time is far from free.

Comment: @TJJ, Check here how Apple implemented "happy eyeballs"  https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/v6ops/current/msg22455.html - even they give 25ms "handicap" to IPv6 over IPv4. And this apparently is more IPv4-fair than "before Happy Eyeballs", where IPv6 was getting 100x more time. That's the kind of preferences i was talking about. If Google was to remove the handicap in their products, i bet their IPv6 stats would drop 10x, from 17%(week) - 20%(weekend) to <2% ;-)

Comment: @NasBanov You're free to use Firefox - but they also implement Happy Eyeballs. Anyway, if Google prefers connections over IPv6, why not give them priority? What's the bad bias about them?

Comment: @TJJ because IPv6 is unnecessary complication for end users and providers. Termination points can be IPv4, we haven't ran out of address space, rather it was abused unwisely by carriers. IPv6 complications should stay at and be handled by carriers (and yes, Google can drop themselves in that bucket). And IPv6 has clear benefits only for "the whales", for "minnows" and "dolphins" it's a royal PITA

Comment: @NasBanov No, IPv6 is not unnecessary. Most end users don't even get in contact with which IP they use, so there's no complication for them. On the contrary: with IPv6 they don't need to care about port forwarding. End-to-end communcation, especially with UDP, which is used for VoIP, becomes possible. And yes, we do have run out of addresses. Just think of all the mobile devices. Having to rely on cloud services for every single application because of missing E2E-connectivity, THAT is the real PITA!

Comment: @TJJ if IPv6 is coming to solve E2E connectivity issues, it's 15-20 years too late - that was solved by router NAT, users don't care about port forwarding. In the case of UDP this is done with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching for what, 5-10yrs now - does not require cloud service continuous bridging.
I grant you that there is not enough IPv4 addresses for every living person on Earth to "get" one, that is true

Comment: Is an indiscriminate, open IP connectivity between any 2 devices a good idea though? I think not - cue the random spam robo-calls we get on our phones daily. NAT unintentionally but effectively has helped in securing our homes/offices, establishing connections should be initiated from inside-out

Comment: But there aren't even enough IP addresses for proper NAT. Carrier-grade NAT seems to be standard for many many ISPs out there. And whole-punching also doesn't seem to be enabled on most mobile connections (3G/4G networks). So, if we like it or not, IPv4 with or without NAT will cause more and more problems.

Comment: Not impactful? How about all the mobile users? Or ISPs in developing countries? They don't have enough money to buy these ridiculous expensive IPv4 addresses. Thought Stackoverflow wants to be part of the future. I know there are some layer 8 issues, but we all have to overcome them. Let's just build the future.

Comment: Four years later, back to the issue. The other day I had to use Internet from my phone (tethering), which was only serving IPv6 (since recently)... It's likely to happen more and more. "We have more pressing things to do" -- what's more pressing than a non-reachable website?

Comment: `Even more important things are in queue` -- As a long time SO user I strongly suggest you guys drop those things because a lot of them are less important than being reachable. Whatever you guys think are important are truly not as important as you think they are.

Comment: Some connections is v6 only these days, or with a overloaded v4 CGNAT. (resulting in SO being unreachable)

Answer (score 1):

It seems hard to find real data on what % of the Internet traffic is IPv6 vs IPv4.

The data that is readily available and shoved in your face is by promoters of IPv6 conversion (like WorldIPv6Launch.org, Google and Akamai) - who however don't tell you such number but instead should for another statistic - the % of Internet users could use IPv6 now, if say IPv4 suddenly dropped dead somehow - and per Google it's somewhere around 15% now (that includes both dual stack and single stack). The bias in presenting the info is understandable in the case of WorldIPv6Launch, which is a "stooge" :) to promoting IPv6. Akamai does it, since their concerns are carrier-grade ones, just like the ISPs.

Now, another question - how much of the Internet *actually* runs on IPv4 v. IPv6 - that one was hard to find, at least for me. So far i only ran into this paper https://thesai.org/Downloads/Volume7No12/Paper_33-Analysis_of_IPv4_vs_IPv6_Traffic_in_US.pdf . I hope the data they use is correct, supposedly couple of data sets from CAIDA for Chicago and San Jose data centers of Equinix. Quick glance at the charts shows that **IPv6 traffic is <1%**, the other 99% being IPv4.

Does somebody have better data at hand? I am am unsure about the paper and journal reliability.

Comment: https://www.google.com/intl/en/ipv6/statistics.html

Comment: If you don't trust the data of google, akamai, apnic and ripe then you have a problem except you have an own source. I can't force you to trust someone. Additionally the statistics have some minor differences. In Germany a very popular it-news-portal and forum has recently published his access by IPv6:  https://m.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/IPv6-Tunneldienst-SixXS-schliesst-die-Tore-endgueltig-3663270.html

Comment: @DavidG - that is the *wrong* kind of statistics, did you read what i said above? It shows % reaching google over IPv6, where IPv6 is preferred. That was not the question!

Comment: @ThomasSchäfer - i trust google and akamai but their statistics shows something *else*. Please pay close attention what they show and what i ask? Remember the "3 types of lies: lies, damn lies and statistics"? The data they show is absolutely, 100% correct. It is a convenient statistics though - seeing 16% there does not mean 16% of the internet is running on IPv6...

Comment: @NasBanov How do you define internet? Packets? Users? (Web)-Servers? If 100%of the users use IPv6, automatically also every packet is IPv6. I showed you a statistic from heise - they count user accesses. I also provide you a number from my campus(Munich), without URL, because the statistics are not public: The IPv6-part on the whole traffic in/out from/to the campus is ca. 19% (Trafficbytes not Users, the campus hasn't finished the IPv6-rollout) The de-cix unfortunately  doesn't publish separate IPv6-statistics since 2013.

Comment: You doubt to much. You could setup you own mail, web ...- server with the ultimate killer app - then you can count v4 and v6-bytes - I hope you trust yourself. If IPv4 would suddenly dropped - stackoverflow would be offline. Other services (like Facebook or google)  would only have 80% less users. My systems would work further without big problems.

Comment: @ThomasSchäfer - i admit i did not understand what the Heise page talks about, since can't read German (google translate only part helpful). What i gather is that SixXS was a "IPv6 tunnel broker" (rfc3053) service who was making it easy to run IPv6 over existing IPv4 networks - and that they have decided to discontinue that in an activist effort to push ISPs implementing native IPv6 - because that is easy for ISPs now. This will sound like conspiracy theory - but why doesn't de-cix publish IPv6 stats since 2013? ;-) How odd, no?

Comment: @ThomasSchäfer - i asked for existing statistics. % of datagrams or traffic MB through backbone would do. But no single web properties, pls! Current Google numbers are 14% during the week, 17% on weekend. Google and Facebook are biased because set as "IPv6-preferentials", meaning they always try IPv6 first and fallback to IPv4 on failure.

Comment: @ThomasSchäfer, saying "IPv4 would suddenly dropped... My systems would work further without big problems" is like saying "what if the EU electrical power grid suddenly fails - i will do w/o big problems because my house has solar panels". Well, no! Maybe you'll have power for your TV/computers/phone but that will do you no good since the providers will be down. In the same way the IPv4 backbone cannot vanish and leave IPv6 working

Comment: Your assumption was to drop IPv4 suddenly not to break down the wires. e.g. bgp-failures could drop down IPv4 while IPv6 would be still running. In that case 30% of the users in US and Germany would have still Internet with a limited offer of services, Netflix and YouTube would work, the German public TV wouldn't.

Comment: https://m.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/IPv6-Tunneldienst-SixXS-schliesst-die-Tore-endgueltig-3663270.html?view=zoom;zoom=1 that's​ a diagram, IPv6 part of the whole traffic to heise, time

Comment: Why are google and Facebook"biased"? It is normal behavior, that dualstack-clients prefer IPv6 to dualstack-server. Some CGNAT-gateways in Germany would crash more often otherwise.

Comment: You want statistics closer to the backbone: http://v6asns.ripe.net/v/6?s=_ALL;s=FI;s=NO;s=CH;s=DE;s=JP;s=FR

Comment: Gack! v6asns.ripe.net/v/6 is the *wrong* stats to look at - how many times do i have to repeat this? ;-) How many % are "enabled" for IPv6 says nothing about real usage/traffic.

Comment: Facebook are extremely biased because internally they tunnel IPv4 traffic inside IPv6. I had some exchange with Paul Saab trying to figure out why their IPv6 connectivity is faster than IPv4 - well duh, why wouldn't be if they had handicapped IPv4 (as if running it in molasses emulation mode). The real problem is that he goes around and misleads people by showing charts how their IPv6 connectivity is "40% faster", not mentioning it's not equal foot comparison

Comment: @NasBanov There is not "IPv6-preference" by Google, Facebook, etc. The preference is made by your computer. If a site is accessible by IPv6, it will use IPv6, the site itself doesn't have much to do with it (well, they could tweak it so that IPv6 is slower to respond, but that would be biased again then, wouldn't it?). And why is the amount of megabytes so important for you? What's wrong with a chart showing number of connections instead of number of packets?

Comment: @TJJ seems you have no idea... A typical dual-stack gives heavy preference for IPv6, when both A and AAAA records are returned from DNS. Did you think it tries connecting to both IPv4 and IPv6? Not in your life... they have tried and IPv4 was connecting faster than IPv4, so they "spike the punch". Per RFC 6555 "those dual-stack hosts have a very strong preference to use IPv6 (with timeouts in the tens of seconds before they will attempt to use IPv4)." - and to fix that they came with "Happy Eyeballs" algorithm, advocating "more aggressive" approach of decreasing the preference for IPv6.

Comment: @NasBanov I'm not sure if it is you that has no idea? you even mention "Happy Eyeballs", otherwise known as fast fallback, where indeed connections on both IPv4 and IPv6 are tries. And again, the preference is not made by the site, but by your computer. Yes, there are techniques to make IPv6 replies be faster (or better: less slow) than IPv4. But if Facebook prefers IPv6 and is more responsive over this connection, why is it biased? They want you to connect using IPv6, but provide IPv4 fallback for those who cannot.

Comment: @TJJ - "there are techniques to make IPv6 replies be faster (or better: less slow) than IPv4" - you are being a spin doctor here. All other things being equal, IPv4 connects faster than IPv6 - it was mentioned in some of the docs. Hence handicaps are being implemented by dual-stacks to slow down IPv4, so that IPv6 has an effing chance. You can't call that "making IPv6 faster than IPv4", just like you wouldn't call puncturing someone's car tire "making me faster".

Comment: Regarding FB, find the Saab presentation about how they implement IPv6 and you'd be aghast of lame reasons and abuses of partitioning IP ranges to rack space... "because we can with IPv6". And then they actually tunnel IPv4 over IPv6 ... why surprised then that FB's IPv4 is slower than their IPv6 and they want to push people to IPv6? It's a self-inflicted wound, converted into other people's problem

Comment: I see more wounds inflicted by limited E2E connectivity. However, I do agree that the IPv6 assignment scheme is bad and that IPv6 could be implemented much better (e.g., instead of giving prefixes to companies, prefixes should be assigned by region, which would significantly decrease routing tables). Also, there's no real mechanism to understand what the end of a prefix delegation should be. If it's a cell phone, it's fine. But as soon as the cell phone is used with tethering, it would have to assign addresses to the devices that connect to it. Now, one of the devices could be a router.